# Aluminum square tubing as cantilever

Tags: mechanical-engineering

How much mass can be attached at the end of aluminum square tubing (6063 T5, 1x1”, 1/16 thick 8’ long tubing supported for the length 1’, cantilever approximately 7’.
I want to run my dogs with atv and tie them to the tubing so they stay away from the all terrain vehicle (atv). They will pull, somewhat down. I like Aluminum since it is light, but you can recommend better material. Thanks.

Comment: a lot will depend on the other end of the ube, how it's fastened - can you draw a sketch with dimensions?

Comment: Please do not use an abbreviation that is familiar to you but not necessarily known by others. What is atv?

Comment: I am intending to use 3/8 bolt to attach the tubing between two 2x8” boards that will be bolted to the atv front rack and dogs will be attached on a hook of the same size few inches from the free end of the tubing which gives about 7’ cantilever. But again looking for suggestions...